# How to get Virtual Machine Maximum Memory using WMI?

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, hyper-v, wmi

On a Windows 2012 R2 virtual machine running under Hyper-V, Task Manager has the ability to display a virtual machine's maximum memory when the virtual machine is using dynamic memory, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I've tried navigating through the following classes but I can't find what I need:

- Win32_OperatingSystem (TotalVisibleMemorySize only shows what the VM has consumed so far - not what the maximum is)
- Win32_PhysicalMemory
- Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray
- Win32_ComputerSystem (TotalPhysicalMemory only reports the same as TotalVisibleMemorySize above - i.e. the first of the Committed memory values)

Is it possible to programatically query using WMI or Registry to obtain this Maximum Memory value from inside the virtual machine itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern operating systems (Windows 8/2012 and newer) includes a class named **Win32_PerfRawData_Counters_HyperVDynamicMemoryIntegrationService** under the namespace **root\cimv2**

This class has a property named **MaximumMemoryMBytes** which shows the maximum memory, also seen in Windows 2012 and above Task Managers.

VBScript Sample Code:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_Counters_HyperVDynamicMemoryIntegrationService",,48)
For Each Item in colItems
    Wscript.Echo "Maximum memory in Megabytes  " & Item.MaximumMemoryMbytes
Next
```

Powershell sample code:

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace root\cimv2 -class Win32_PerfRawData_Counters_HyperVDynamicMemoryIntegrationService | Select-Object MaximumMemoryMBytes
```

This class does not exist in Windows 2008 R2/Windows 7 or earlier operating systems.

More information about this class can be found [here](http://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_perfrawdata_counters_hypervdynamicmemoryintegrationservice/)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but I got troubled by this for a long time so...

`Get-Counter "\Hyper-v Dynamic Memory Integration Service\Maximum Memory, Mbytes"`

As far as I understand, the VM doesn't know if dynamic memory is enabled, it only knows how many memories have been allocated and the memory cap.